# Google Cloud VM instance Share

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have two vm instance . I  want to give permission as compute admin to different users for both machines. Means two different owner of two Instance.

Comment: Are the instances created in the same project?

Comment: yes same project

Answer (score 0):

At Google Cloud Next 2018, Google announced [Compute Engine resource-level IAM](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/get-more-control-over-your-compute-engine-resources-with-new-cloud-iam-features).

Inside a same project, you can now grant **directly** different roles to your Compute VMs to different users. If your use-case is to have 2 users (`user1@mydomain.com` and `user2@mydomain.com`), each one admin of a specific instance (relatively `instance1` and `instance2`), you can define the following YAML files :

```
# instance1_policy.yaml

bindings:
- members:
  - user:user1@mydomain.com
  role: roles/compute.admin
```

and

```
# instance2_policy.yaml

bindings:
- members:
  - user:user2@mydomain.com
  role: roles/compute.admin
```

And apply the policies (merge the following files with the existing VMs IAM policies if you need so, check by using `gcloud compute instances get-iam-policy` before) :

```
gcloud compute instances set-iam-policy --zone=<INSTANCE1_ZONE> instance1 instance1_policy.yaml
gcloud compute instances set-iam-policy --zone=<INSTANCE2_ZONE> instance2 instance2_policy.yaml
```

Note also that IAM policies applying on your project can interfer with these policies. For example, if `user1@mydomain.com` have `roles/compute.admin` role on the project, then he may also have access to `instance2`, "ignoring" your policy on `instance2` VM (he have inherited `roles/compute.admin` role from the project).